# E_INVALIDARG when creating texture2d from DDS dxt5 compressed

Tags: c++, directx, dds-format

Doing all work about processing from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Detect headers,get pitch from this formula:

```
max( 1, ((width+3)/4) ) * block-size  (block-size == 16)
```

then trying to `CreateTexture2D( &texDesc, resData, &texture );`

I filled all fields from header. But always get `E_INVALIDARG`.
Can't find out my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your ID3D11Device with the debug flag [D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff476107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look at the error explanation in the output window.